# How to select range from source sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is a really newb question (I do apologise). - I have this script below that copies data from one sheet into another workbook. It works perfectly except I want to change the 'source' to a specific range (A4:E17):

```
function transferList() {
  var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Cancellations");
  var sourceData = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var targetSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById("*****************").getSheetByName("Cancellations");
  var targetRangeTop = targetSS.getLastRow();
  targetSS.getRange(targetRangeTop+1,1,sourceData.length,sourceData[0].length).setValues(sourceData);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed `sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();` to `sourceSheet.getRange("A4:E17").getValues();`